# Upgrading Postgres from 10 to 12 -- problem with encodings

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to upgrade a postgres server from 10 12, and am having problems with the encodings.  I'm following what I believe to be established recipes.

Behold:

```
postgres@serverbot:~$ psql -l
                              List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding  | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges
-------------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres    | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     |
 template0   | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
             |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1   | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | postgres=CTc/postgres+
             |          |           |         |       | =c/postgres
 thingsboard | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =Tc/postgres         +
             |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres+
             |          |           |         |       | nagios=c/postgres
(4 rows)
```

Notice the encodings on the 10 database.  Time to create the database for 12.

```
postgres@serverbot:~$ sudo service postgresql stop

postgres@serverbot:~$ /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/initdb -E SQL_ASCII --locale=C  -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/data
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

creating directory /var/lib/postgresql/12/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... America/New_York
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/data -l logfile start
```

Excellent!  Let's fire up the new server.

```
postgres@serverbot:~$ /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/data -l logfile start
waiting for server to start.... done
server started
```

And verify the encodings...

```
postgres@serverbot:~$ psql -l
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding  | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     |
 template0 | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

Everything matches... time to upgrade!

```
postgres@serverbot:~$ /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_upgrade \
--old-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/10/main \
--new-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/12/main \
--old-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin \
--new-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin \
--old-options '-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf' \
--new-options '-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf' \
--link --check
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is the install user                  ok
Checking database connection settings                       ok
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok
Checking for reg* data types in user tables                 ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch       ok
Checking for tables WITH OIDS                               ok
Checking for invalid "sql_identifier" user columns          ok

encodings for database "postgres" do not match:  old "SQL_ASCII", new "UTF8"
Failure, exiting

postgres@serverbot:~$
```

Doh!

What is wrong here?  I assert that the encodings do match, and I'm stuck.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I see is:

```
postgres@serverbot:~$ /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/data -l logfile start
waiting for server to start.... done
server started
```

and then:

```
postgres@serverbot:~$ /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_upgrade \
--old-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/10/main \
--new-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/12/main \

[...]
```

Note the `$PGDATA` directories. The database cluster you did the `initdb` for is different from the one you are doing the `pg_upgrade` to.

**UPDATE**. Since you seem to be using a Debian based OS and it's Postgres packaging, it might work better to stick with the packaging tools:

```
sudo pg_createcluster  --locale=C 12 ascii 
Creating new PostgreSQL cluster 12/ascii ...
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/ascii --auth-local peer --auth-host md5 --locale C
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "SQL_ASCII".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/12/ascii ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... America/Los_Angeles
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:


    pg_ctlcluster 12 ascii start

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
12  ascii   5434 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/ascii /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-ascii.log


postgres=# \l
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding  | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
 template0 | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

Also I would use `pg_upgradecluster`, see [here](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/postgresql-common/pg_upgradecluster.1.en.html) for more information. This keeps everything in the same system.

Comment: You nailed it.  I had a (apparently) already created a db at /var/lib/postgresql/12/main with UTF encoding (or maybe it was created during install?), and this is what the upgrade command was seeing.  Clearing out the wrong version and fixing the folder names solved the problem.  Sometimes it's the simple things that trip you up.  Thanks!!

Comment: Well it is down to mixing systems. You have a packaging system that is doing one thing and you are manually doing something else. Working against the package manager is going to cause problems.  To keep similar issues from arising in future I would take a look at the information [here](https://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql).

Comment: This is good advice;  I generally like to use the package manager when I can, but until I read your post, I didn't realize the package manager had a way to do this different from Postgres.  I figured my problems were due to different layouts between different linuxes.

Comment: Yes the Debian based package manager allows for relatively easily running multiple instances of Postgres on one machine. They can be mixes of PG versions and clusters within a version. You can see what has been set up with `pg_lsclusters`